# Save multiple reports, but specify file path one time

Tags: ms-access

Hi I am trying to save multiple reports from my Access database.  I am using the "ExportWithFormatting" function to save my reports to PDF.  I would like to be able to specify the path of the first report, and then the subsequent reports would automatically saved to specified path.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have code that runs your reports? If so, please post it.  Yes, you can use VBA to run reports and save wherever you want.

Comment: I don't have any code.  I am using the Macro builder tool.

Comment: Need more detail. How will you determine which reports to run? All? Table containing report names? All report names that start with 'Annual...'? 'hard-coded list? Will reports need customized filters when they run / or where will criteria come from?

Comment: 10 reports are run which are specified in my macro (the macro builder tool, not VBA code). I'm using a "ExportWithFormatting" action item for each report. But when each report is saved to PDF the user must specify the path each time.  If I can get to the actual macro vba code I could probably figure it out, but this macro builder tool seems very limited and I wouldnt be able to code the whole thing from scratch. I should also add that the reports are run when the user clicks a button on my form.

Comment: You don't mention your Access version, but in 2010 you can convert macros to VBA by using the following instructions: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/convert-macros-to-visual-basic-HP005186676.aspx

Comment: Thanks Wayne! Can't believe I missed that.